# How to install service on Windows XP Embedded SP3

Tags: windows-xp-embedded

How to install service on Windows XP Embedded SP3 without re-building the installation image? 
I realized that I didn't install service on the O/S after building.

Are there any ways to add service?

[image]

Comment: I'm lack of reputation. so I couldn't.

Comment: I uploaded it on the profile pic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XP Embedded but if you have access to cmd.exe, you maybe use `sc create service path opt1 opt2`

`sc /help` for more details

Comment: Thanks for your feeback. but, the system doesn't have sc.exe it doesn't work.